# Can a pivot table have a N:N relationship with another table?

Tags: mysql, database

Let's consider we have a pivot table: **days_times**
and we have a table: **classes**.
Is it possible **days_times** has a N:N relationship with **classes**? Is it standard?!
Or **classes** should has a N:N relationship with **days** and **times** separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely want

```
CREATE TABLE Schedule  (
    ClassID INT NOT NULL,
    Day DATE NOT NULL,
    TimeOfDay TIME NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ClassID) REFERENCES Classes(ClassID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Day) REFERENCES Days(Day),
    FOREIGN KEY (TimeOfDay) REFERENCES Times(TimeOfDay)
)
```

Assuming classes, days and times look like

```
CREATE TABLE Classes (
    ClassID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ClassName VARCHAR(N) NOT NULL,
    ... Other Columns
)

CREATE TABLE Days (
    Day DATE PRIMARY KEY,
    ... Other Columns
)

CREATE TABLE Times (
    TimeOfDay TIME PRIMARY KEY,
    ... Other Columns
)
```

Comment: Your answer is quit right and I liked that,but there are few questions about that:
1-What is the primary key of **schedule**?
2-what about normalization rules about **schedule**?Is it normal?